# How to extracting formula from a number sequence

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

I have following sequence:

```
| Term  | Value |
|-------+-------+
| 0     | 0     |
| 1     | 1     |
| 2     | 2     |
| 3     | 2     |
| 4     | 3     |
| 5     | 3     |
| 6     | 3     |
| 7     | 3     |
```

and so on...

which the relation is `T(n)=T(floor(n/2))+1, T(0)=0`, I am wondering how to extract the exact function of it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The values you listed don't satisfy $T(6)=T(3)+1$

Comment: Thanks, I edit it.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve this recurrence relation, or how to find the relation in the first place? Because if it's the latter, then it is not possible to do it uniquely without additional context. For example $-\frac{5 n^7}{1008}+\frac{89 n^6}{720}-\frac{877 n^5}{720}+\frac{865 n^4}{144}-\frac{277 n^3}{18}+\frac{6793 n^2}{360}-\frac{3103 n}{420}$ satisfies the same data.

Answer (score 2):

Checking further, you will get $T(8) = T(9) = \ldots = T(15) = 4$, then $T(16) = \ldots = T(31) = 5$, etc. You can prove, such as by using [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) (which I'll leave to you to do), that for $n \gt 0$ you get $T(n)$ being the number of digits of $n$ in its binary expansion, i.e., $T(n) = \lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor + 1$ (note for the proof, it'll likely be easier to show for the integer $k$, where $2^k \le n \lt 2^{k+1}$, that $f(n) = k + 1$).